Lower Bound on Product of Expectation for Random Variables
Take two random variables $X, Y > 0$ and a constant $c > 0$ such that $XY \geq c$ almost surely. Then, it is clear that $\mathbb{E}[XY] \geq c$. However, is it also true that $\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]\geq c$?
It seems to be true, via the following proof:
\begin{align}
XY \geq c
&\implies
\log X + \log Y \geq \log c \\
&\implies
\mathbb{E}[\log X] + \mathbb{E}[\log Y] \geq \log c \\
&\implies
\log\mathbb{E}[X] + \log\mathbb{E}[Y] \geq \log c \\
&\implies
\log\Big(\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]\Big) \geq \log c \\
&\implies
\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y] \geq c,
\end{align}
where the first step is due to $\log$ being an increasing function, second step is due to linearity of expectation, third step is Jensen's inequality, fourth step are $\log$ properties, and final step is again due to the increasing nature of $\log$.
Is this proof correct? Does the property hold? Is this a well-known result?

Jensen's inequality gives
$E[1/X] \ge \frac{1}{E[X]}$ and therefore
$$E[X] E[Y ] \ge E[X] E[c/X] \ge c.$$

Cool! That is simpler and easy to verify. I am accepting this answer as it confirms the hypothesized result via an alternate proof.

Your proof is correct.
I do not believe it is a well-known result (at least, not well-known enough to have a name).
Interestingly, even though $\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)\ge c$, there is no nonzero lower bound on $\min(X,Y)$. For example, for $t\in(0,1)$, we could take $$
X=\begin{cases}t &\text{w.p.} \frac12 \\ \frac1t & \text{w.p.} \frac12\end{cases}
$$
and take $Y = \frac1X$. Then we have $XY=1$, and $\mathbb{E}(X) = \mathbb{E}(Y) = \frac12\left(t + \frac1t\right)$, which is strictly greater than $1$ for all $t\in(0,1)$. However, $\min(X,Y)=t$, which may be arbitrarily small.
As a similar example, we could take $X\sim \mathrm{Unif}(0,1)$ and $Y=\frac1X$. Then $XY\ge1$ almost surely, and $\mathbb{E}(Y)=\infty$ so $\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y) = \infty > 1$, but $X$ may be arbitrarily close to $0$.

Thanks for your answer! That is a very interesting addendum to the original result.

A proof without Jensen's inequality: since $(X, Y) \in D = \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}_+^2 : xy \geqslant c \}$ and the region $D$ is closed and convex, we have $(\mathbb{E} [X], \mathbb{E} [Y]) = \mathbb{E}[ (X, Y) ] \in D$. Hence $\mathbb{E} [X] \mathbb{E} [Y] \geqslant c$.
The proof clearly generalizes to an arbitrary closed and convex subset $D$ of the plane, not just $xy \geqslant c$.
